# Update Access Table to MySQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have a problem with exporting ms access (2013, 2016) data to mysql.

Primary I am using access. I need to "export" one table out of my access database to use it on my homepage. I tried the ODBC drivers and it works really fine.

There is only one little problem. The export doesn't work anymore if the table is already excisting on mysql. I need a solution with that I can update the content of the table on mysql all few days.

Thanks for yout help

Answer (score 1):

Why not just linking to server's table from Access. Then you can just update the table in Access, no to export anymore.

Comment: I read about a connection between access and mysql, but the other way round. It will update the data in access using the data from mysql. I need to update the data in mysql, because I am working and changing data in access. Maybe you could help me how it works correctly?

Comment: A connection is a connection. It works both ways. You just need to download and install the right odbc driver, then "link" or "attach" the mySql (or SQL Server or Oracle or...) into your Access db, and from that moment it will behave just like any other Access table, except that it's on a server somewhere on the world.